# Why Javascript sliders break my css flex layout?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, swiper.js, lightgallery

i am learning css flexbox and i have one problem with javascript sliders. I have tested several (lightgallery.js, swiper.js, siema.js) but everytime it seems to break my flexbox container.

I have a main element and an aside element. On mobile, i wish that the main and the aside elements could be one below the other. It seems to work well. But on a desktop, i wish that the main element fits 2/3 of the max 1000px and the aside element fits 1/3, side by side.

Unfortunatelly, the slider seems to break my .wrap container.
I have tested a lot of things and searched for problems like mine but without result. I don't really understand what could solve my problem. I must admit i'm a bit lost.

You can see this problem on this pen (lightgallery.js) :
https://codepen.io/studiok7/pen/pxGWMJ

```
<span>Thanks ;-)</span>
```

Comment: You can use something like: flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 * 2);

Comment: ahh nice. appreciate that you deleted the pen for it ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default the flex items (children of flex layout) have the min-width set to auto, so that the parent would show all elements without clipping/overflow. Try adding:

```
.main {
...
    min-width: 0;
}
```

to the .main element, as shown in the forked example below: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVPLOo

Comment: Thank you @Piotr-Wicijowski ! It's so simple in fact ! I just have to keep learning. Thanks again !

Comment: You saved me a complete hour of my life

Comment: also happens with swiper JS - thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much !! I don't really understand why, as the Swiper is many (block-)elements below the flex item I added this to, but it solves the slides getting initiated way too big (millions of pixels at times).

Comment: Unbelievable, thanks a lot Piotr. I spent hours looking where the error was. I litterally dded min-width: 0 to the container of my Swiper (which is the child item of a flex) and the problem was solved. I dont even understand the problem, but thanks!

Comment: you are such a lifesaver min-width:0 in flex and min-height:0 in flex col is one of best tricks ever